# I can't use .LoadedBehavior in my MediaElement code in WPF

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

I try to write this code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {


        InitializeComponent();


        PlaySw1Element.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

        PlaySw1Element.Source = new Uri("/Media/Film/starwars1.wma", UriKind.Relative);        

        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);

    }
```

and visualstudio 2012 underlines in red LoadedBehavior and MediaState.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Can you please show more code? And also share what it is you want to achieve?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: LoadedBehavior: missing using or assembly
(sorry my visual studio is in ita)

Comment: and mediastate doesn't exist in current contest

Comment: i tryed to put: PlaySw1Element.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
everywhere, also in button click event, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit LoadedBehavior in XAML if you have access to it, for example:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="PlaySw1Element" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
```

Since probably you won't like to change it, this should work.

---

EDIT: If you don't want to edit the XAML (or you can't do it for any reason), you should try to import this at the beginning of your code, since MediaState is defined here.

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

Comment: in xaml LoadedBehavior doesn't exist in type mediaelement and in the code behind i just use System.Windows.Controls.
Thanks however.

Comment: i tryed to edit xaml an added LoadedBehavior="Manual", but the message is "doesn't exist in type mediaelement"

Comment: Ok, I got it. My question now is: which version of the Framework are you using? This would be most likely the issue, if you are using an old version. Go to "Project->Properties (the last button)->Destination Framework". What's written there?

Comment: i have italian version of visual studio 2012...
in nuget i have only installed "Windows phone Toolkit" and the project is in Windows phone 7.1